# How to get a connection from Java DataSource without a username and password?

Tags: java, jndi, websphere-8, jaas, ejb-2.x

In an ejb after I look up a secured javax.sql.DataSource using its global JNDI name e.g. jdbc/MyDS (not resource reference) is there a way to get a connection via getConnection().

This is on WAS 8.5.5 and the data source has both a container managed and component managed authentication alias with "Mapping-configuration alias" of none and test connection is successful in the WAS admin console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct lookups (when no resource reference is used) default to application-managed authentication (sometimes also referred to as component managed authentication), which means that the application is responsible for supplying or not supplying the the user/password. You should be able to use both getConnection methods: getConnection() without a user/password if you do not wish to supply user/password, and getConnection(user, password) if you do wish to supply user/password.

The other way to get application-managed authentication is to use a resource reference and configured it with `res-auth=Application`. If a resource reference does not specify, the default is `Container`.

If you don't supply a user/password on the getConnection request when using application managed authentication and your DataSource requires a user/password (which you have indicated is the case here), then you will need to either have the component managed authentication alias or a user/password configured as custom data source properties (most JDBC vendors tend to support user/password as data source properties)

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply.

Direct lookup of DataSource and getConnection without arguments work in a web app on WAS 8.5 but fails within an ejb with java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException invalid userid password

However the ejb app is a legacy app currently running on WAS 6 that I am deploying on WAS 8.5. It is strange that getConnection without arguments works on WAS 6 but fails on WAS 8.5